# How to save a Pharo Smalltalk package to disk in Tonel format?

Tags: pharo

I would like to write Pharo Smalltalk scripts that load and save Smalltalk packages to disk in tonel format but I don't understand the API for saving packages.

Loading from Tonel on disk into the image works like this:

```
(TonelReader on: aRepositoryDirectory fileName: packageName)
    version load.
```

but what is the inverse operation that saves a package onto disk? (assuming that the package name and target directory are supplied.)

(I explicitly want to avoid using advanced tools like Metacello and Iceberg here. I want to either use the Tonel library directly or else Monticello without depending on any previous repository configuration.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps unsurprisingly, it looks like the inverse of `TonelReader` is implemented by [`TonelWriter`](https://github.com/pharo-vcs/tonel/tree/ba3884c81af180e2a88fb216167b5b6897b729d5/MonticelloTonel-Core.package/TonelWriter.class):

```
[[[ TonelWriter on: ('someDirectory' asFileReference ensureCreateDirectory) ]]]
```

Here is a full example courtesy [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523491/luke-gorrie):

```
[ :packageName :directory |
      TonelWriter fileOut:  packageName asPackage mcWorkingCopy on: directory.
] value: 'BaselineOfTonel' value: '/tmp/tonel-test'
```